# Looping to add to datagridview ends in out of range

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

i have an example code i created.
however, when i run in, i get an out of range error, and cannot seem to find the reason.

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
int myRow = -1;
int myCell = -1;
foreach (var i in list1)
    {
     myRow = myRow+1;
     foreach (var d in list2)
     {
          myCell = myCell+1;

          dataGridView1.Rows[myRow].Cells[myCell].Value = i + " and " + d; 
     }
}
```

i'd appreciate any help.
thanks!

Comment: Do you have any rows already ? cells in those rows ? 
Are you sure that your rows are have the same count as list1 ?
and your cells have the same count as list2 per row ?
Make sure to get your rows count while debugging as well as your cells per row

Comment: Please read a tutorial on DataGrids. That's not how you work with `DataGrid`s - you do not push data into them, you let them pull data from their data source.

Comment: also put the code how you have defined your datagridview1 ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for you. This is tested also.

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            int myRow = -1;
            int myCell = -1;
            foreach (var i in list1)
            {
                myRow = myRow + 1;
                foreach (var d in list2)
                {
                    myCell = myCell + 1;
                    if(dataGridView1.Rows.Count==1)
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(list1.Count);
                    dataGridView1.Rows[myRow].Cells[myCell].Value = i + "and" + d;
                }
                myCell = -1;
            }
```

Dont forget to mark as answer

Note: First row will be the header here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set your `myCell`back to `-1` after the 2nd foreach.

Add your row in the foreach too, since you cant select a row that is not there.

Right now it keeps on going up

```
int myRow = -1;
int myCell = -1;
foreach (var i in list1)
{
 myRow = myRow+1;
//add the row here
 foreach (var d in list2)
 {
      myCell = myCell+1;
      //add the cell here

      dataGridView1.Rows[myRow].Cells[myCell].Value = i + " and " + d; 
 }
myCell = -1;
}
```

better even would be to set `myRow` and `myCell` on `0` initialy and increase them at the end of a loop.

i.e.

```
int myRow = 0;
foreach(var i in list1) {
//DO YOUR STUFF
myRow++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

or use simple `for` loop :

```
for(int row = 0; row < list1.Count(); row++)
{
    for(int cell = 0; cell < list2.Count(); cell++)
    {
         dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[cell].Value = i + " and " + d; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First add the row to the gridview and then you can fill its value.